# no targets specified in the manifest - either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, vscodium

I'm following the instructions in the book "The Rust Programming Language" to build a guessing game, but whenever I try to run my code (via the command `Cargo run`) in the VSCodium (Open source version of VSCode) terminal, my code refuses to run due to the following error:

```
no targets specified in the manifest
  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present
```

here's what my Cargo.toml file looks like:

```
[package]
name = "GuessingGame"
path = "src/GuessingGame.rs"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
authors = ["my name <example@example.com>"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

VERSIONS:
VSCodium: 1.73.1
OS: Zorin OS 16.2

i tried changing `[package]` to `[[bin]]` and `[lib]`, but it gave me more errors, being:
`this virtual manifest specifies a [lib] section, which is not allowed`
and
`this virtual manifest specifies a [[bin]] section, which is not allowed`

Comment: Can you execute `cargo build` in terminal? What files do you have in `src`?

Comment: ```cargo build``` returns the same error, and the only file i have in ```src``` is GuessingGame.rs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the configuration you want, you need to specify the package *and* the target, separately.

```ini
[package]
name = "GuessingGame"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[[bin]]
name = "GuessingGame"
path = "src/GuessingGame.rs"


[dependencies]
```

That said — please *don't* override the path. Rust projects are more readable when they stick to [the standard project layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html), which is auto-detected by Cargo.

To do this, make your source file have the name `src/main.rs` instead of `src/GuessingGame.rs`, and leave out the `[[bin]]` section and `path` entirely from your `Cargo.toml`. The built executable will still be named `GuessingGame` automatically, because that's your package name.